# JsChart height issue

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am using jschart to render bar chart of the data. Everything work fine but the height of chart is not enough to show the data vertically. As you can see in attached image for 100% the 00% part is cut and only 1 is shown. I tried setting height within div tag and setting responsive:true but it stretches badly and labels,bars etc don't become clear. Below is my code

```js
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            var patternSize = 20;
            // Bar chart
            new Chart(document.getElementById("mychart"), {
                type: "bar",
                data: {
                    labels: ["1.1","1.2","1.3","1.4","1.5","2.1","2.2","2.3","2.4","2.5","2.6","2.7","2.8","3.1","3.2","3.3","3.4","3.5","4.1","4.2","4.3","4.4","4.5",],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: "Progress",              
                        backgroundColor:"#ff0000",
                        data: [74.5,70.8,20,16.7,0,90,43.3,17.8,37.5,100,11.3,4.6,0,100,12.5,0,15,0,44.4,0,0,0,20,],        
                    }
                ]
                },
                options: {  
//                  responsive: true,           
                    maintainAspectRatio: false, 
                    legend: {
                    display: true,
                    position: 'bottom',
                    },      
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            gridLines: {
                                display: true
                            },
                            stacked: false,
                            ticks: {
                                stepSize: 20,
                                callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                                return  value + '%';
                                }
                            },
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                fontSize: 18,
                                fontColor:"#000000",
                                fontStyle: "bold",
                                labelString: 'Percentages'
                            }
                        }],
                        xAxes: [{
                            stacked: false,
                            gridLines: {
                                display:false
                            },              
                            ticks:{
                                maxRotation: 90,
                                minRotation: 90,
                            },          
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                fontSize: 18,
                                fontColor:"#000000",
                                fontStyle: "bold",
                                labelString: 'ACTIVITY'                         
                            }
                        }]
                    },
                }, //end options
/**value on top of bar**/

plugins: {
          
          afterDatasetsDraw: function (context, easing) {
            var ctx = context.chart.ctx;
            context.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
              for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
                if (dataset.data[i] != 0) {
                  var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;
                  var textY = model.y + (dataset.type == "line" ? -3 : 15);

                  ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                  ctx.textAlign = 'start';
                  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
                  ctx.fillStyle = dataset.type == "line" ? "black" : "black";
                  ctx.save();
                  ctx.translate(model.x, textY-15);
                  ctx.rotate(4.7);
                  data=" "+dataset.data[i]+"%";
                  ctx.fillText(data, 0, 0);
                  ctx.restore();
                }
              }
            });
          }
        
      }                                                 
/**end value on top of bar**/
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart chart-lg" id="chart-wrapper">
<canvas id="mychart"></canvas>
</div>
```

[chart issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcYbb.jpg)

Comment: AFA I see, you are using CHART.js 2.4.0. Since version 3, the bar dataset has got the clip option, which will enable you to manage the clip area of the chart. By default, the chart area is clipped and with a plugin you can not draw outside that area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your use case and the issue is not the clip but there is not space on top of chart area to draw your labels. You should add padding on top of the chart in order to show the labels, by `options.layout.padding` configuration.

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");   
var patternSize = 21;
Chart.plugins.register({
  afterDatasetsDraw: function (context, easing) {
    var ctx = context.chart.ctx;
    context.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
      for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
        if (dataset.data[i] != 0) {
          var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;
          var textY = model.y + (dataset.type == "line" ? -3 : 15);
          ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
          ctx.textAlign = 'start';
          ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
          ctx.fillStyle = dataset.type == "line" ? "black" : "black";
          ctx.save();
          ctx.translate(model.x, textY-15);
          ctx.rotate(4.7);
          data=" "+dataset.data[i]+"%";
          ctx.fillText(data, 0, 0);
          ctx.restore();
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["1.1","1.2","1.3","1.4","1.5","2.1","2.2","2.3","2.4","2.5","2.6","2.7","2.8","3.1","3.2","3.3","3.4","3.5","4.1","4.2","4.3","4.4","4.5",],
     datasets: [{
       label: "Progress",  
       backgroundColor:"#ff0000",
       data: [74.5,70.8,20,16.7,0,90,43.3,17.8,37.5,100,11.3,4.6,0,100,12.5,0,15,0,44.4,0,0,0,20,],        
     }]
  },
  options: {  
        layout: {
          padding: {
            top: 50
          }
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false, 
        legend: {
          display: true,
          position: 'bottom',
        },      
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
              display: true
            },
            stacked: false,
            ticks: {
              stepSize: 20,
              callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                return  value + '%';
              }
            },
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              fontSize: 18,
              fontColor:"#000000",
              fontStyle: "bold",
              labelString: 'Percentages'
            }
          }],
          xAxes: [{
            stacked: false,
            gridLines: {
              display:false
            },  
            ticks:{
              maxRotation: 90,
              minRotation: 90,
            },          
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              fontSize: 18,
              fontColor:"#000000",
              fontStyle: "bold",
             labelString: 'ACTIVITY' 
            }
          }]
        }
    },
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 617px;
  max-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.4.0/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="617" height="250"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```